# How can I compare a unicode type to a string in python?

Tags: python, unicode, python-2.7, list-comprehension

I am trying to use a list comprehension that compares string objects, but one of the strings is utf-8, the byproduct of json.loads.  Scenario:

```
us = u'MyString' # is the utf-8 string
```

Part one of my question, is why does this return False? :

```
us.encode('utf-8') == "MyString" ## False
```

Part two - how can I compare within a list comprehension?

```
myComp = [utfString for utfString in jsonLoadsObj
           if utfString.encode('utf-8') == "MyString"] #wrapped to read on S.O.
```

EDIT:  I'm using Google App Engine, which uses Python 2.7

Here's a more complete example of the problem:

```
#json coming from remote server:
#response object looks like:  {"number1":"first", "number2":"second"}

data = json.loads(response)
k = data.keys()

I need something like:
myList = [item for item in k if item=="number1"]  

#### I thought this would work:
myList = [item for item in k if item.encode('utf-8')=="number1"]
```

Comment: part 1 returns true to me.

Comment: returns True for me too, are you in python3?

Comment: [In python3](http://ideone.com/F3BI7d)

Comment: Are you looking for `us.decode('utf-8')`? Doesn't json handle the unicode parsing for you? What are you trying to do?

Comment: I will add more complete code to show exactly what's happening.

Comment: Fixed the example - that was just a typo.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You must be looping over the wrong data set; just loop directly over the JSON-loaded dictionary, there is no need to call `.keys()` first:

```
data = json.loads(response)
myList = [item for item in data if item == "number1"]
```

You may want to use `u"number1"` to avoid implicit conversions between Unicode and byte strings:

```
data = json.loads(response)
myList = [item for item in data if item == u"number1"]
```

Both versions **work fine**:

```
>>> import json
>>> data = json.loads('{"number1":"first", "number2":"second"}')
>>> [item for item in data if item == "number1"]
[u'number1']
>>> [item for item in data if item == u"number1"]
[u'number1']
```

Note that in your first example, `us` is **not** a UTF-8 string; it is unicode data, the `json` library has already decoded it for you. A UTF-8 string on the other hand, is a sequence *encoded bytes*. You may want to read up on Unicode and Python to understand the difference:

- [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) by Joel Spolsky
- The [Python Unicode HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html)
- [Pragmatic Unicode](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html) by Ned Batchelder

On Python 2, your expectation that your test returns `True` would be correct, you are doing something else wrong:

```
>>> us = u'MyString'
>>> us
u'MyString'
>>> type(us)
<type 'unicode'>
>>> us.encode('utf8') == 'MyString'
True
>>> type(us.encode('utf8'))
<type 'str'>
```

There is **no** need to encode the strings to UTF-8 to make comparisons; use unicode literals instead:

```
myComp = [elem for elem in json_data if elem == u"MyString"]
```

Answer (score 12):

You are trying to compare a string of bytes (`'MyString'`) with a string of Unicode code points (`u'MyString'`).  This is an "apples and oranges" comparison.  Unfortunately, Python 2 pretends in some cases that this comparison is valid, instead of always returning `False`:

```
>>> u'MyString' == 'MyString'  # in my opinion should be False
True
```

It's up to you as the designer/developer to decide what the correct comparison should be.  Here is one possible way:

```
a = u'MyString'
b = 'MyString'
a.encode('UTF-8') == b  # True
```

I recommend the above instead of `a == b.decode('UTF-8')` because all `u''` style strings can be encoded into bytes with UTF-8, except possibly in some bizarre cases, but not all byte-strings can be decoded to Unicode that way.

But if you choose to do a UTF-8 encode of the Unicode strings before comparing, that will fail for something like this on a Windows system: `u'Em dashes\u2014are cool'.encode('UTF-8') == 'Em dashes\x97are cool'`.  But if you `.encode('Windows-1252')` instead it would succeed.  That's why it's an apples and oranges comparison.

Comment: Why is it apparent that the OP is using Python 2? If it were Python 2, his test would return `True`, **not** `False`.

Comment: Looks like I repeated his typo back to him.  He explicitly states Python 2 after his edit so I'll edit my answer too.

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming you're using Python 3. `us.encode('utf-8') == "MyString"` returns `False` because the `str.encode()` function is [returning a bytes object](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.encode):

```
In [2]: us.encode('utf-8')
Out[2]: b'MyString'
```

In Python 3, strings are [already Unicode](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#text-sequence-type-str), so the `u'MyString'` is superfluous.