# Peewee query results, unicode data not comparable to regular strings in list

Tags: python, unicode, peewee

I have a query built with peewee:

```
nameGoEvidenceEarlier = Protein.select(Protein.entryname ,Evidence.evidencecode ,Go.go_domain, Go.go_term).join(ProteinGo).join(Evidence).switch(ProteinGo).join(Go).where(Evidence.ondate.year == 2013).order_by(Protein.entryname).naive()
```

I then iterate over the query result:

```
for earlier in nameGoEvidenceEarlier.iterator():
earlierDict[earlier.entryname] = earlierDict.get(earlier.entryname,[]) + [(earlier.go_domain,earlier.evidencecode,earlier.go_term)]
```

A list contains the following items:

```
nonexpEvidenceList = ['IEA','ISS','ISO','ISA','ISM','IGC','IBA','IBD','IKR','IRD','RCA','TAS','NAS','IC','ND']
```

Then I iterate over the dictionary earlierDict and compare to see if the 1st value of the tuple (earlier.evidencecode) is in nonexpEvidenceList:

```
for entryname,earlier_ontologyCodeTermList in earlierDict.items():
for o,c,t in earlier_ontologyCodeTermList:
    if c.encode('ascii') in nonexpEvidenceList:
       print c
```

However this piece of code does not print anything. One obvious conclusion that one can make is that c does not exist in nonexpEvidenceList but this is not the case- when I printed c, all the codes available in the list exist.
My guess is that the type casting is going wrong somewhere.

Am I overlooking something?

Comment: what does `print type(c)` show, if you put as the first line in your for loop? `<type 'unicode'>`?

Comment: Also, Martijn Pieter's answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16471332/how-can-i-compare-a-unicode-type-to-a-string-in-python) may be instructive.

Comment: jedwards: print type(c) in the first line of loop shows type unicode

Comment: Then you likely want `if c.encode(<encoding>) in nonexpEvidenceList:` -- where `<encoding>` is the encoding of your database (e.g. `UTF-8`, etc).

Comment: How will it compare c to a list which has regular ascii symbols?

Comment: Also it is peewee's query results that turn out to be UTF-8 encoded. I have tried both 1)putting the items in list and c as UTF-8, 2) putting the items in list and c as ascii