# Python, Check if a string exists in an XML tag

Tags: python, xml

am trying to read a word from a text file and check if this word exists in an xml tag, alse the file contains special characters.
This is the code:

```
import lxml.objectify
from lxml import etree
import codecs
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
file_path = "C:\Users\HP\Downloads\Morphalou-2.0.xml"
for event, elem in ET.iterparse(file_path, events=("start", "end")):
    if elem.tag == 'orthography' and event =='start':
        data = elem.text
        f = codecs.open ('test.txt', encoding="ISO-8859-1")
        for line in f:
            check = line
            if check in data:
                print (check,":", "true")
                break
        else:
                print (check,":", "false")
                break
    elem.clear()
```

When I tipe `print (check)`, the word looks axactly how I want it "garçon", but when I add the test

```
     if check in data:
                print (check,":", "true")
                break
        else:
                print (check,":", "false")
                break
```

This is what i get :

```
(u'gar\xe7on', ':', 'false')
```

Thought the result has to be true!! Am missing something, does anyone    know what it is,  Please Help! Advance Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I compare a unicode type to a string in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16471332/how-can-i-compare-a-unicode-type-to-a-string-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you print it like this?

```
print (a,b,c)
```

If you just want to format the output as a:true, please try to do it like this:

```
print "%s:true" % check
```

Because Python thinks you are printing a tuple.

This is the sample:

Comment: I tried that but this came out when i run the program: 
There is an error in your program : Can't assign to fuction: line 11 which is  `print ("%s:False"%check)`